# SQL join table 2 find

Tags: mysql, sql

Table reserve

```
sib   boot_id   day

22    101       10/10/1996
22    103       11/12/1996
```

Table Sailors

```
sid   sname   rating   age

22   dustin   7        45.0
31   lubber   8        55.5
58   rusty    10       35.0
28   yuppy    9        45.0
44   gruppy   8        55.5
```

The result I want is find name who borrow all boot ?

Comment: What do you want again? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should definetely try a basic tutorial, there is a good one at Khan Academy: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql.

It is a simple join. Since one person has both items, I've also included a distinct not to repeat the name.
Your answer is :

```
select distinct ts.sname 
from Table_Sailors as ts
inner join Table_Reserve as tr on ts.sid = tr.sib
```

Just change the table names, Table_Sailors and Table_Reserve, to whatever table name you have in your database.